# Java accessing specific element in array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am running a web crawler for my own use. I downloaded one and want to provide it with seeds. I want to provide it with around 50 seeds. So I created an array of strings. I want to provide the crawler with 1 seed each time it goes through my for loop. My code is :

> String[ ] temp = new String[ ]
>   {"http://www.random.org/","http://www.wikipedia.org/",
>   "http://www.jlworld.com/","http://www.frys.com/"};
>
> String[ ] urls = new
>   String[temp.length];
>
> ```
>   for (int i = 0; i <=temp.length; i++)       
>      {          
>         urls[i] = temp[i];      
>      }
> ```

The crawler needs a string assigned to urls. So like :

> String[ ] urls = new String[1];
>
> urls[0] = "http://www.google.com/";

So it works like that. I get an outofbounds exception though for my code. What I want to do is provide the crawler with 1 of the seeds each time it goes through the for loop. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, instead of using the loop yourself, look into System.arraycopy (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <=temp.length; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <temp.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
```

Calling `.length` on an array returns the size of the array, but array indices are 0-based.  For your loop, you were correct in starting with `i = 0`, but you only want to go to `i = (temp.length - 1)` or you will get an index out of bounds exception.  Comparing `i < temp.length` instead of `i <= temp.length` accounts for this shift in index basing.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "1-based size". The size is the size. If there are 10 elements in the array then the size is 10. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
for (int i = 0; i <=temp.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
```

You were looping one too many times

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {          
    String url = temp[i];      

    ... handle url...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a Map of [URL, seed] pairs instead of raw arrays?  Do the lookup using the URL and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

```
 for (int i = 0; i <temp.length; i++)       
 {          
    urls[i] = temp[i];      
 }
```

Array index start from 0 to length-1