# How to collect CSV row as array of strings using simpleflatmapper

Tags: java, arrays, csv, java-stream

I'm trying to collect CSV row as array of strings using [simpleflatmapper](https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper):

```
try (Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader("path")) {
    return org.simpleflatmapper.csv.CsvParser
//  .mapTo(String[].class)
    .stream(in)
//  .parallel()
//  .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .map(line -> {return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line));})
//  .map(Arrays::asList)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As I debug, the `line` is `String[]` but the value is entire row (one element) instead of many strings (many cells). How can I got the array of cells?

The CSV file is no special. Ex:
    a\t b\t 1\t 2
    x\t y\t 3\t 4

The issue as I see in this code `.map(line -> {return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line));})` that the `line` contains one string value that is the whole line (with tab, space, ...) instead of many strings (each string is the value of each cell).

The whole result I want is `List<List<String>>` (List of lines). Each line is `List<String>` (list of cells). The current result is list of lines (rows), each line/row is the whole string.

Comment: What CSV parser are you using? Web search seems to only find `CSVParser` classes. No `CsvParser`. Since your question is about the Stream generated by `CsvParser`, how do you expect us to help, when we have no clue what it is?

Comment: I'm using simpleflatmapper.

Comment: I have written that I'm using simpleflatmapper but there are three down votes because of this.

Comment: Because few on here know of simpleflatmapper, and you didn't link to it or show import statement. "simpleflatmapper" sounds like something related to the Stream `flatMap` method, which threw us all for a loop. Also, you haven't shown us the input, so how would we know what you're expecting to see. Perhaps if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you wouldn't get down-votes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java accessing specific element in array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069870/java-accessing-specific-element-in-array-of-strings)

Comment: instead of returning an ArrayList in your map operator, [read the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069870/java-accessing-specific-element-in-array-of-strings) and wrap it into a new Object and return this one back to your stream..

Comment: I don't want to parse the CSV line to cells by myself.

Comment: I have assumed that the library will give me the line that is the arrays of cells. So I mapped the array to ArrayList for adding new column later. But the library gives me the whole line. I don't know why: I'm missing some things or the library was missed this?

Answer (score 0):

since the file is CSV, you don't need to use any external lib, so simply you have to read the file as you read a txt file like this

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("MyFile.csv"));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
myArray=scanner.nextLine().split(",");
}
```

Comment: We must use a library here.

Comment: No you don't to use any external lib unless if that the requirment

Comment: Yes, that is the requirement.

Comment: This will only work if the CSV has no quoted fields with delimiters and line breaks inside. Also, it will be way slower than using a proper library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
return org.simpleflatmapper.csv.CsvParser
                    .separator('\t')    //<-- solution
                    .stream(in)
                    .map(Arrays::asList)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks all!